# Differences between "Share Side effect" and "Share Resources"

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm studying RxSwift and RxCocoa.
There are these explanations in the official document.

1. Share side effect
2. Share resource

Are they the same?
If there is a difference, what difference is there?
I don't understand just the explanations in the official document.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: What official document? Can you provide a link to where these terms are used?

Comment: I was wondering when I looked at the document on the link below. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md

Comment: Driver
- Can't error out.
- Observe occurs on main scheduler.
- Shares side effects (share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)).

Comment: Signal
- Can't error out.
- Delivers events on Main Scheduler.
- Shares computational resources (share(scope: .whileConnected)).
- Does NOT replay elements on subscription.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation shows exactly what it means by "Shares side effects" and "Shares computational resources" in the parentheses beside each phrase.

The phrase "Shares side effects" means it uses `share(replay: 1, scope: .whileConnected)` while "shares computational resources" means it uses `share(scope: .whileConnected)`.

That tells you that sharing side effects will replay the last emitted value for every new subscription while sharing computational resources will not. Otherwise, they are the same.